# how to use this jquery validator in my form

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I found a nice jquery script for US zip code validation: http://igorgladkov.com/resources/demos/jquery.validator/demos/zip_us_validation.html
If the entry is valid the script writes valid if not it writes invalid as you can see :)
Now I want to use this in my form:

```
 <form action="search-by-zip.php" method="POST"">
        <span>zip-code:<input type='text' name='zipcode' value='' size='8' maxlength='7' /></span>
        <span>Distance:
            <select id="radius" name="radius">
                <option value="5">5 miles</option>
                <option value="10">10 miles</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="25">25 miles</option>
                <option value="50">50 miles</option>
            </select>
        </span>
        <input type="submit" value="Find Head Shops" name="find">
    </form>
```

I guess it must be possible?
Instead of getting Valid message I just want to submit my form and get results listed on same page. How I am supposed to do. I am not very familiar with javascript.

Comment: can show us your javascript?

Comment: sorry, didn't see your respond, here is the script: http://jsfiddle.net/9nrqT/

Answer (score 0):

have a look to http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ ..uses jquery,easy to use,customize, proper documentation, demos and tutorilas...
just need to load the related js file and call

```
 $('#yourFormId').validate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make this :

```
$('#zipcode').validator({
        format: 'zipUS',
        invalidEmpty: true,
        correct: function() {
            $('#validation_result').text('VALID');//Not needed
            $('form').submit();
        },
        error: function() {
            $('#validation_result').text('INVALID');
        }
    });

    $('#submit_button').click(function(e) {
        $('#zipcode').validator('validate');
    });
```

Change your HTML to this :

```
 <form action="search-by-zip.php" method="POST"">
        <span>zip-code:<input type='text' id='zipcode' name='zipcode' value='' size='8' maxlength='7' /></span><br />
        <span id="validation_result" class="result"></span><br />
        <span>Distance:
            <select id="radius" name="radius">
                <option value="5">5 miles</option>
                <option value="10">10 miles</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="25">25 miles</option>
                <option value="50">50 miles</option>
            </select>
        </span>
        <input type="button" id='submit_button' value="Find Head Shops" name="find">
    </form>
```

I add a **validation_resut span**, change the submit button to a **simple button**, and add an **id** to the **text input**.

I fixed some little bug, and It works... Test [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9nrqT/)

Comment: I tried your solution but nothing happens actually, validation doesn't work this way at all :(

Comment: Thanks for update. It works now but with a little problem, I cant change any value in drop down list as soon as I insert valid zip code and click anywhere else on page it redirects me to action script immediately. Its not what I want, I want to click submit button to be redirect. Thanks.

Comment: For information, my code should be correct. However, it seems to trigger the validator on blur... I don't know why! Otherwise, when you think the answer is correct, please accept it. Thank's for us!